# (ReactJS) Radio input selection persists visually after re-render

Tags: reactjs, input, radio-button, render, reset

I'm trying to set up a simple, quick example app in React and am encountering this weird issue with radio inputs. I have 3 radio input options, lined vertically, and they have certain values. When a button element is clicked, the 3 radio options get replaced with different ones and the inputs have new values to reflect that replacement. It seems like re-rendering does occur, at least to some extent.

For some reason, though, if the Button is pressed while one of the radio inputs is selected, that input appears to remain selected when the new options appear. However, the debugger shows that there is no actual selected value for the 3 new options, so that filled radio icon is a visual bug/artifact. The inputs get replaced, they have their proper new values and everything, so it seems like the component re-rendered. But the selection doesn't disappear. Like if the first radio option is chosen/filled, then the Button element is pressed and the options get replaced, that first radio input still appears filled.

Another thing indicating that the issue is visual is that clicking the Button element when this happens after the re-render doesn't trigger its effect unless one of the options is clicked again; so it doesn't detect that persisting filled radio as being an actual selection.

Has anyone encountered this problem, or might know how to fix it?